# JQUERY modal box confirm form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

I have a form that when the submit is hit i want a modal box to pop up with a YES and NO button i want the both the yes and no button to submit the form but i need to know which button they clicked.

Here is my code

```
<input onclick="$.msgbox('confirm text',{
  buttons : [
    {type: 'submit', value:'YES'},
    {type: 'submit', value:'NO'}
  ]
}, function(buttonPressed) {

});" name="btnApply" id="btnApply" tabindex="41" src="images/btnsubmit.jpg" style="border-width: 0px;" type="image" />
```

My problem is the form is submitting when the user clicks submit.

Any help or ideas would be great

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I'm not familiar with the `$.msgbox` plugin but you should be opening the modal dialog on `<form>` submit and not on a button press, as the form can also be submitted by an enter/return on certain input fields (like text boxes `<input type="text|password">`)

```
var confirmed = false;
$('#myform').bind('submit', function() {
  if (confirmed) {
    return true;  // confirmation received, continue form submission process
  } else {
    $.msgbox(
      'my modal message',
      {
        buttons : [
          { type: 'button', value: 'YES' },
          { type: 'button', value: 'NO' }
        ]
      }, 
      function(buttonPressed) {
        confirmed = buttonPressed.value;  // Update the confirmed variable
        $('#myform').submit();  // re-submit the form
      }
    );  
    return false;  // cancel form submission
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add return false:

```
<input onclick="$.msgbox('Would you like a cash advance of up to £1000 whilst we process your loan?',{
  buttons : [
    {type: 'submit', value:'YES'},
    {type: 'submit', value:'NO'}
  ]
}, function(buttonPressed) {

}); return false;" name="btnApply" id="btnApply" tabindex="41" src="images/btnsubmit.jpg" style="border-width: 0px;" type="image" />
```

Comment: Hay thanks that is preventing the form from submiting but when the YES or NO button is clicked in the box nothing happens how do i get the yes abnd no button to submit the form thanks

Comment: in your function:
`$('#idfortheform').submit();`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the `msgbox` either but some remarks about your code:

1. Don't attach your JS logic directly to your code, but use jQuery to attach click event to your markup (see [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)):

   Instead of

   ```
   <input onclick="$.msgbox('confirm text',{
   ```

   Use

   ```
   $('#btnApply').click(function(e) {
   ```
2. You can stop the click handling by setting as false [one property](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) of the event parameter:

   ```
   $('#btnApply').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // stop click handling and so form submitting
   ```
3. Finally, handle the form submitting or not in the `msgbox` callback function:

   ```
   $.msgbox("Are you sure that you want to permanently delete the selected element?", {
   type: "confirm",
   buttons: [
       {
       type: "submit",
       value: "Yes"},
   {
       type: "submit",
       value: "No"},
   {
       type: "cancel",
       value: "Cancel"}
   ]
   }, function(result) {
       if(result == "Yes") // display the form on submit
            $('form').submit();
   });
   ```

[jsFiddle available.](http://jsfiddle.net/UpHyc/)